# When a react component gets unmounted, does the custom hook triggers its useEffect cleanup?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a custom hook that is used for alert banners, it utilizes the `setTimeout` for displaying the banner after three seconds.

custom hook

```
export const useBanner = () => {
    const [alerts, setAlerts] = useState([]);

    const addAlert = (message: string) => {
        const newAlertObj = {
            id: `success-${performance.now()}`,
            message,
            timerId: undefined,
        };

        newAlertObj.timerId = setTimeout(() => {
            removeAlert(newAlertObj.id);
        }, ALERT_DELAY_MILLISECONDS);

        setAlerts((prev) => [...prev, newAlertObj]);
    };

    const removeAlert = (id: string) => {
        setAlerts((prev) => prev.filter((alert) => alert.id !== id));
    };

    const clearTimers = () => {
        alerts.forEach((alert) => clearTimeout(alert.timerId));
    };

    return {
        alerts,
        addAlert,
        clearTimers,
        removeAlert,
    };
};
```

However, I need to add a cleanup for these timeouts whenever a component gets unmounted. I have added a `useEffect` where the component is using the custom hook. So when the component is unmounted, the `clearTimers` will trigger.

```
const ComponentA = () => {
  const {clearTimers, addAlert, alerts} = useBanner()

  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      clearTimers()
    }
  }, [])
  ....
}
```

`addAlert` is only triggered when a button is clicked, fyi.

My question is if I were to move the `useEffect` cleanup inside the custom hook instead, when the component gets unmounted, does the custom hook's `useEffect` cleanup gets triggered?

custom hook with useEffect cleanup

```
export const useBanner = () => {
    ....

    const clearTimers = () => {
        alerts.forEach((alert) => clearTimeout(alert.timerId));
    };

    useEffect(() => {
      return () => {
        clearTimers()
      }
    }, [])

    return {
        alerts,
        addAlert,
        clearTimers,
        removeAlert,
    };
};
```

I'm trying to avoid memory leaks, the way I have it does the job (`useEffect` cleanup in the component). However, if I ever want to use this custom hook in another component, then I'm obligated to add the `useEffect`. This doesn't seem ergonomically.

I've searched for more info on this, but I haven't found much about it. Unless I overlooked.

I'm trying to understand more about component unmounting, but I don't know much about what happens when it's using a custom hook with a `useEffect` cleanup. What is the process behind it.

Your help will be appreciated, thanks :)

Comment: as long as you are using the custom hook it your component, the hook's effect's cleanup should also run when the component unmounts.

Comment: also, you are missing the dependency array in the useBanner, meaning the effect and the cleanup will run on every render.

Comment: Oh right, I missed that array in the `useEffect`.  It's edited now

Comment: you can do `useEffect(() => clearTimers, []);` inside your hook or *(preferrably not)* in the component. I'd not expose `clearTimers` at all outside of the hook.

Answer (score 2):

As long as you are using `useBanner` in your component, the `useEffect` cleanup will be called when the component unmounts. So this code will work for you:

```
const useBanner = () => {
    ...
    useEffect(() => {
        ...
        return clearTimers()
    }, [])
    ...
}
```

And just use `useBanner` in your component.

Comment: Adding a ref would be wonderful for guys who loves to read in the official doc or something like that